# How do I find missing files from a backup?

Tags: linux

So I want to backup all my music to an external hard drive.  This worked well for the most part using Grsync, but some didn't copy over because of encoding issues with the file name.

I would like to compare my two music directories (current and backup) to see what files were missed, so I can copy these over manually.

What is a good solution for this?  Note there are many many files, so ideally I don't want a tool that wastes time comparing the file contents.  I just need to know if a file is missing from the backup that is in the source.

Are there good command line or gui solutions that can do this in good time?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the top level directory in each set.

```
find . -type f -print | sort > /tmp/listfile.txt
```

Set up a sorted list for each directory, and `diff` should help you spot the differences.